# Nested for loop in python when range is not a number

Tags: python

I have a hard time understanding this:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
  for j in range(i):
    print(i)
```

when the inner loop's range is a number I understand it, but on the code above, the inner loop is running in range(i). What does that mean? Thank you.

Comment: `i` is set by the outer range on each iteration to be `1`, `2`, `3`. That *is* a number actually.

Comment: When `i` is 1, the inner loop runs `range(1)` times, when `i` is 2, inner loop runs `range(2)` times....so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear now. But why for I in range(5, 0) doesn't give any output?  Shouldnt it give 5,4,3,2,1?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step:

1. The function `range(start, stop, step)` has these 3 parameters.
2. The parameters `start` and `step` are optional, but the parameter `stop` is required.
3. If you only send one parameter to the function, for example, `range(5)`, the function automatically will set `start = 0` and `step = 1`. Then, `range(5)` is equal to `range(0, 5, 1)`.
4. The parameters `start`, `stop` and `step` **must be integers**. In your case, `i` is an integer variable that is taking the values `1`, `2` and `3`, and that's why `range(i)` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a variable set by the loop it is inside of. `i` is the number iterating (that's why it's commonly called i). j then iterated through all the numbers up to `i`.

For example, `range(1,4)` could be 3 sizes of sweets where each size up has one more sweet (1 packet with 1 sweet, 1 packet with 2 sweets, 1 packet with 3 sweets). The second loop iterates through each of the sweets in the packet (where packet is `i` and sweet is `j`). You're then printing the packet you ate.